# Where is the Visual Studio 2010 debug toolbar?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, toolbars

I recently installed the offical release of Visual Studio 2010 Pro.  I can never remember the debug key bindings, so in previous versions of VS I would enable the debug toolbar.  In VS2010, however, when I right-click on the toolbar area and select Debug, no debug toolbar shows up.  If right-click again on the toolbar area, it shows Debug with the check next to it.  What might I be missing?

Comment: The toolbar exists. Is the space wide enough in the toolbars area ?
Have you removed commands from the Debug toolbar somehow so it is empty ?

Comment: OK, there it is.  I maximized VS and there it was to the right on the first row.  Thanks

Comment: The odd thing about this was that the "more toolbars" icon (the one with dropdowns that gets wedged in when there isn't enough space in a given toolbar row) didn't get displayed until I maximazed and then restored VS2010.  So when I originally enabled the debug toolbar, there was no visual inidicator that a new toolbar was available.